# The server tag is not well formed, ASP Repeater Datasource

Tags: asp.net

I've been getting parser error with message The server tag is not well formed for the following line.

```
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="<%# ((MultilistField)((Item)Container.DataItem).Fields["Tags"]).GetItems() %>">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer1" runat="server" FieldName="Tag name" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <SeparatorTemplate>
                        /
                    </SeparatorTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

The syntax looks fine, but one thing I'm not sure about is whether you can use the ".Field["tags"] element in there.

I've tried looking it up, but couldn't find a similar problem.  I'm hoping someone provide me with some insight to why the parser is complaining about this line.

Thanks

Comment: trying using single quotes for DataSource instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What comes into my mind right now is to use a single-quoted string instead:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# ((MultilistField)((Item)Container.DataItem).Fields["Tags"]).GetItems() %>' >
```

Comment: You guys are magical!  Can't believe I haven't tried that.  I try to changed the inside double quote to single, but that didn't work.
Thank you all a bunch!

Comment: @STi88 - That's because single quotes are not valid string delimiters in C#/VB.NET.

Comment: @Oded Yep you are correct, I was just desperate for a solution... Can't believe the thought of the outside single quote slip pass me.

Answer (score 3):

You have double quotes within the attribute. This confuses the parser - it can't tell where the attribute ends.

Wrap the attribute in single quotes to fix it:

```
DataSource='<%# ((MultilistField)((Item)Container.DataItem).Fields["Tags"]).GetItems() %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

try ' instead of " it might work

else try binding from code behind

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# ((MultilistField)((Item)Container.DataItem).Fields["Tags"]).GetItems() %>' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a closing tag? i.e.

```
</asp:Repeater>
```

Otherwise you are missing the / at the end of your tag declaration.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="<%# ((MultilistField)((Item)Container.DataItem).Fields["Tags"]).GetItems() %>" />
```